# In Jetpack-Compose, How to achieve longClick on ClickableText?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I tried using like

```kotlin
val isHover = remember { mutalbeStateof(false) }
val isClick = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
LaunchEffect(isHover) {
     delay(1000)
     if(!isClick.value && isHover.value){
          /// invoke long click function
     }
}
...in ClickableText ...
onHover = {
    isHover.value = true
}
...
onClick = {
   isClick.value = true
   ...some logic...

}
...
}
```

but this approach is not work cause isHover.value = true make recompose. so onClick is not invoked after onHover.

I think If I can propagate my click event to parent something like `Box()` or `Column()` it could be solve but I don't know the way.

before I used `ClickableText` I used on parent(Column) `Modifier.combinedClickable()` and as child `Text()` but I have to add a function like partial clickable in text, so I choose `ClickableText()`

I need longclick + click(normal) + partial text click

Answer (score 0):

I used `Modifier.pointerInput(onClick)`, is from `ClickableText()`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ClickableText(
    text: AnnotatedString,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    style: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    onClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val layoutResult = remember { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null) }
    val pressIndicator = Modifier.pointerInput(onClick) {
        detectTapGestures { pos ->
            layoutResult.value?.let { layoutResult ->
                onClick(layoutResult.getOffsetForPosition(pos))
            }
        }
    }

    BasicText(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier.then(pressIndicator),
        style = style,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        overflow = overflow,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        onTextLayout = {
            layoutResult.value = it
            onTextLayout(it)
        }
    )
}
```

in my case, I use just `Text()` and used `onTextLayout:(TextLayoutResult)->Unit` to get offset of text. And put `pressIndicator` on `Text()` `modifier = Modifier...some chain...then(pressIndicator)` like above `ClickableText`

```kotlin
            val pressIndicator = Modifier.pointerInput(onClickWord) {
                detectTapGestures(onTap = { pos ->
                    
                    textLayoutResult.value.let { layoutResult ->
                        val index =
                            layoutResult?.getOffsetForPosition(pos) ?: return@detectTapGestures
                        text.value.getStringAnnotations("move", index, index)
                            .firstOrNull()?.let {
                                // detect annotaion
                                onClickWhereInSmallTitle.invoke(it.item)
                            } ?: run {
                            // else onClick normal
                            onClickWord.invoke(jeolDto)
                        }
                    }
                }, onLongPress = {
                    onLongClickWord.invoke(jeolDto)
                })
            }
```